# How can I set max-height of an image?

Tags: css

I have a list of images like this:

```html
<img class="d-block w-100" src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhE...">
```

I want to set a `max-height: 300` and height & width to `auto` in order to keep the aspect ratio correct.

But in the Dev Tools, when I try to add `max-height: 300;` to `.w-100` like this:

```css
.w-100 {
    width: 100% !important;
    max-height: 300;    
}
```

the `max-height: 300;` style is marked as `Invalid property value`. How can I set `max-height` for the `<img>`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to provide a unit, for example `px`

```css
.w-100 {
    width: 100% !important;
    max-height: 300px;    
}
```